# How to update CRD object for Traefik in Kubernetes

Tags: kubernetes, kubernetes-helm

I'm currently trying to setup a Kubernetes/K3s deployment according to the following manual (https://github.com/ct-Open-Source/team-container).
Unfortunately I get an error during the installation of Traefik through Helm.

-> Error: INSTALLATION FAILED: failed to install CRD crds/traefik-crds.yaml: unable to recognize "": no matches for kind "CustomResourceDefinition" in version "apiextensions.k8s.io/v1beta1"

From my understanding the error is related to the different Kubernetes releases.
My current cluster is running kubelet version v1.22.7+k3s1.

Can anybody help or advise me, how to handle this error?
Thanks for your help.

Comment: I think the related file in the respository is this one.
<https://github.com/ct-Open-Source/team-container/blob/c6374e42afd8a0245f88d3dc2e37724ddff9c33e/team-setup/crds/traefik-crds.yaml>

Comment: this is a better fit for [devops.se] https://devops.stackexchange.com/q/18196/18965

Answer (score 0):

"apiextensions.k8s.io/v1beta1" has been removed in K8s 1.22, you need to use a newer version of traefik, which uses apiextensions/v1. Helm chart version greater than 10 is supporting k8s 1.22:

Try this one:
helm install traefik/traefik --version 10.6.2